# Phone call from plist iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

How can I manipulate this code to have it pull the phone number from a plist?

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:2135554321"]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add your plist into your project (if it s in your bundle) (for example if its a dictionary):

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clubs" ofType:@"plist"];
    telsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

for example, your plist is a `NSDictionary` again:

> {"Mike","2135554321"  "Deniel","2135554322"  "Sandra","2135554323"}

If you want to call Deniel:

```
 -(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {

    NSString* yourActualNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",telsDictionary[@"Deniel"]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourActualNumber]];
}
```

Comment: It is working properly except every time I make the call it calls 685-5. Any Thoughts?

Comment: of course... because you don't have a change method, which decide which number will be call

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have included a file named `foo.plist` into your project, with a string property named `telnum`, the following should work-

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistHash = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
NSString *tel = [plistHash objectForKey:@"telnum"];
```

afterwards you can call `openURL` with the value in `tel`.

Comment: can you be more elaborate.. I am somewhat new to xcode and cannot figure out how to call the tel action from within the callphone