# How can I make different phone calls taken from a plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I know how to make a phone call, but I'm trying to call certain people depending on which table view cell is selected. I viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078308/phone-call-from-plist-ios) question but with no success. In my viewDidLoad method, I created a NSDictionary for the phone numbers:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"State" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into arrays
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
stateNum = [dict objectForKey:@"Phone"];
```

I then sent the number that was selected to my detail view controller in the prepareForSegue method:

```
destViewController.phoneName = [stateNum objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I created an IBAction method and successfully linked it to the button in my storyboard:

```
-(IBAction)phone
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
    openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:plistNum]];
}
```

plistNum is defined in my viewDidLoad method of the detail view controller as:

```
plistNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",stateName];
```

The app compiles and runs, but when I click the button nothing happens. It worked when I had tel:12345678901 in URLWithString but not now. If anyone has any suggestions I would be happy to listen. I am very, very new to this so if you could explain your answer I would appreciate it. Thanks.

**Edit:** @rmaddy helped me find my dumb mistake. I had used stateName in the plistNum String instead of phoneName. There were no messages on the console, the string I had created was just not a phone number. Also, I don't have a viewWillAppear method. Will creating this make the program smoother?

Comment: What's the value of `stateName`? is the `phone` method called? What's the full value of `plistNum`? Do you see any messages in the console? Update your question with these details.

Comment: where does `indexPath` come from in `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: Also, I suggest you move the assignment of `plistNum` from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`.  `viewDidLoad` will execute before you have assigned `phoneName` in `prepareForSegue`